# What is the fourth parameter in InternetReadFileExW used for?

Tags: wininet

What is the last parameter in [`InternetReadFileExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetreadfileexw) used for?

According to the documentation:

> A caller supplied context value used for asynchronous operations.

but I am calling it in synchronous more like so:

```
if( !InternetReadFileExW(hRequest,(LPINTERNET_BUFFERSW)&net_buffer, IRF_SYNC, NULL))
```

So, what should I use as the last argument ?

Comment: It's used if you are using asynchronous operations (`INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC`, `WININET_API_FLAG_ASYNC`). If you're using it in synchronous mode, then it is not used.

Comment: @RaymondChen so what should i use if i am using a synchronous call

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest, and there's nobody around to hear it, what sound should it make? If a callback function is never called, what parameters should you pass to it?